# curl request to get list of values

Tags: curl

I am trying to make a GET request using curl with authorization header. Below is the request. I some how get curl: (3)  malformed error. Here is the request :

curl -i -H "Accept: applicationjson" -H "Authorization: Bearer {{authorizaiton token comes here}}"  -X GET /list/user

Comment: Your first header should be `curl -i -H "Accept: application/json"...`. Where is your URL? Please post all the request...

Comment: and avoid the `-X GET` that's basically never right...